# Parsing JSON-RPC using Python

Tags: python, json, rpc, nonetype

I have an JSON-RPC of the form: [{"priority": "0", "actionsList": [{"type": "OUTPUT", "port": 2}], "match": {"wildcards": 3145968, "nw_dst": "10.0.0.2", "dl_src": "00:00:00:00:01:01", "dl_dst": "00:00:00:00:04:02", "dl_vlan": 65535, "nw_src": "10.0.0.1", "in_port": 3}}, {"priority": "0", "actionsList": [{"type": "OUTPUT", "port": 3}], "match": {"wildcards": 3145968, "nw_dst": "10.0.0.1", "dl_src": "00:00:00:00:04:02", "dl_dst": "00:00:00:00:01:01", "dl_vlan": 65535, "nw_src": "10.0.0.2", "in_port": 2}}]

I parse using the following code:

```
flowTableJSON = do_func(gopts, opts, args)
print type(flowTableJSON)
print flowTableJSON
for flow in flowTableJSON:
        print 'in for loop'
        print flow['match']['dl_src']
        print flow['match']['dl_dst']
```

Printing the variable flowTableJSON outputs the example JSON above, while the type of flowTableJSON is Nonetype. Is it possible for a variable to store a value and be of type Nonetype?

Essentially, I am trying to access the value stored in dl_dst in each of the elements of the JSON; how would I do that?

Comment: What did `do_func` do?

Comment: Does it actually say `Nonetype` rather than `NoneType`? If so, that's some class that someone created that has nothing to do with the type of `None`. (Although I can't imagine why anyone would do something so confusing, it's legal to do so.) Also, are you _sure_ that the JSON output is coming from the `print flowTableJSON` rather than from some other statement in your program? (If so, _why_ are you sure?)

Comment: More importantly, can you just copy and paste the output instead of describing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm willing to bet that the problem is that `do_func` just prints out the JSON and doesn't return anything. So, `flowTableJSON` is `None`, so its type is `NoneType`, and that's printing after the JSON.

I know you said the `NoneType` was printing before the JSON, but you also said it was `Nonetype`, and I find that unlikely, so my guess is you're just being not paying enough attention.